# Automatic generation of dots in Notepad++ when pressing space

Tags: notepad++, text-editor, text-processing, spacing, auto-generate

I am encountering an issue in Notepad++ where dots are automatically generated when I press the spacebar. This behavior is unexpected and causes inconvenience while working with text.

To provide some context, whenever I type a space between words in Notepad++, it automatically inserts a dot instead of a regular space. For example, when I type "hello world" and press the spacebar, it appears as "hello.world" as shown in this screenshot:
[image: screen of point between words]

I have tried investigating the settings in Notepad++ to find a solution, but I haven't been successful in resolving this problem. I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to disable this automatic dot generation when typing spaces.

Comment: **This question should never have been closed!** It was clear even before my earlier edit of embedding the image and had a fully correct answer (which happens to be my answer) long before it was closed. The given close reason of "lacking focus" is total nonsense. Arguably the questions and answers might fit the Super User site better, but given that (1) we have two relevant and accurate answers and (2) Notepad++ is used by many programmers, the question should stay. The closure de-facto just unjustifiedly decreases the questions's visibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `View` -> `Show Symbol` and uncheck `Show Space and Tab`.

By the way, I find this option useful and usually have it turned on. Similar useful options include:

- `Show Non-Printing Characters`
- `Show Control Characters & Unicode EOL`

[image: options for disabling certain visible special characters]

Answer (score -1):

These dots indicate that there's a space at that position. Helpful if you need to check indentation in code files. They are saved as spaces, so it's a feature,  not a bug. To disable,  search for the option "show / hide whitespace" or similar (can't check right now)